# Update the column of table1 and get it on table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I create a query where I can update the table1 column date that I get it on table2?

**Here is some example of the tables**

***Table1:***

```
|   stud_id |   start_date  | birt_date     |   name    |   exam_date   |
|   s001    |   11/19/2018  | 05/20/1999    |   john    |   10/20/2018  |
|   s003    |   01/01/2018  | 05/25/1995    |   mike    |   10/20/2018  |
|   s005    |   12/23/2018  | 02/20/1999    |   ed      |   10/20/2018  |
|   s005    |   12/23/2018  | 02/20/1999    |   ed      |   10/05/2017  |
```

***Table2:***

```
|   stud_id |   start_date  |   exam_date   |
|   s005    |   01/01/2017  |   10/20/2018  |
|   s001    |   01/01/2017  |   10/20/2018  |
|   s003    |   01/01/2017  |   10/20/2018  |
```

Basically I want to change just the `start_date` of the 3 so `s006` will not change.
How can I accomplish that using query? I was thinking using in then select the table but I think its not gonna work.

I need to based on two or more column for the condition of my update so I want to update the table 1 where `table1.stud_id` = `table2.stud_id` and `table1.exam_date` = `table2.exam_date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do join and update

```
update t1 
set t1.stardate=t2.startdate,
t1.exam_date=t2.exam_date
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.stud_id=t2.stud_id
 where t2.stud_id='s003' -- if you just need s003 update
```

Comment: Okay I will try this

Comment: if i do join the one who will be update is the one who exist on table2 right?

Comment: Hi my question is incomplete sorry. Can you help me on my edited question?

Comment: @Jovs answer edited just add others column as like the 1st one in update

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CTE as well to update:

```
;With cte as
(
    select t1.start_date as t1date,t2.start_date as t2date from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
    on t1.stud_id=t2.stud_id
    and t1.exam_date=t2.exam_date

)

update cte set t1date=t2date
```

Comment: Hi my question is incomplete sorry. Can you help me on my edited question?

Comment: You just need to add 1 more condition in your join

Answer (score 1):

You can join the 2 tables:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Start_Date = T2.Start_Date
FROM Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
        ON T1.stud_id = T2.stud_id
            AND T1.exam_date = T2.exam_date
```